# C++ templates no matching function call

Tags: c++, templates, function, function-calls

I have a member function of a template class declared as such:

```
template <class T>
int Data<T>::getPosition(vector<T> stuff, T newStuff, bool ascending)
```

I call this somewhere with the line

```
frequencies.insert(frequencies.begin() + getPosition(frequencies, current, ascending),
                       frequencies[i]);
```

The variables for that line are declared as:

```
vector<T> temp;
vector<int> frequencies;
int current = frequency.find(words[i])->second;
```

However, the call to `getPosition` gives this error:

```
Data.h|158|error: no matching function for call to 'primitives::Data<double>::getPosition(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int&, bool&)'|
Data.h|165|note: candidates are: int primitives::Data<T>::getPosition(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >, T, bool) [with T = double]|
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to provide more context, because it isn't clear how the template parameter T is being picked. Are you calling it from another member function of primitives::Data?

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to pass a vector by value there - that will copy the vector but you'll probably find you can get away with passing it by const ref which is much much more efficient

Comment: @Stewart yes all that code is inside of the primitives::Data class. also, thanks for the suggestion; I'll implement the const reference instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function prototype gets templated on `Data<t>`, and it looks like you're performing this call on an object with type `Data<double>` and passing a `std::vector<int>` and an `int`, when it probably expects a `std::vector<double>` and a `double` to correspond to the initial templated type of the `Data` object.

Comment: You posted it just as I was seconds away from submitting an answer to my own question :)

Answer (score 2):

`getPosition` takes three arguments of type `vector<T>`, `T` and `bool`. The templated type `T` in this case is `double` (as is shown in the error message), and yet you are trying to pass `vector<int>` and `int` as the first and second argument, respectively.

Perhaps the parameters for `getPosition` should not be templated? Depends on what you are trying to achieve - you do have hard-coded int-vectors there, after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<T> temp;
```

Shouldn't T here be some type like int, double or bool?

Comment: Nah, it should be storing stuff of whatever type the `Data` class is.

Comment: OK, well looks like you are using a double for the Data class and it is expecting vector<T> stuff (first param of getPosition) to be double as well. However you are passing it vector<int> for the first position.